# Refresh a div with result after posting to database with ajax and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am writing a Codeigniter app, and I use ajax to send data to my controller/method, and would like to know how to refresh a div using ajax without reloading the entire page  (the path from db to view using ajax is still confusing for me)

I use this code to send data to the database

```
<script>

         $(function(){
        $("#rate").submit(function(){
         dataString = $("#rate").serialize();

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/rate",
           data: dataString,

        });
    </script>
```

The posting to the db works just fine.

Then I have a div in the view that will get the result from the database so I append the code like :

```
<script>

         $(function(){
        $("#rate").submit(function(){
         dataString = $("#rate").serialize();

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/rate",
           data: dataString,


         dataType: "html",
           success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
           }

         });

         return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!

        });
        });
    </script>
```

but nothing happens (I followed some snippets on the net)

Can anyone guide me through ?

Thanks

**UPDATE** 
//Controller

```
function rate(){

            if ($this->input->post('e1') || $this->input->post('e2') || $this->input->post('e3') || $this->input->post('e4') || $this->input->post('e5'))
            {
                $this->Mproduct->rateProduct();
                                $this->db->cache_delete_all();

            }

        }
```

//Model

```
public function rateProduct()
    {
      $data = array('usage' => $_POST['e1'],
                    'packing' => $_POST['e2'],
                    'size' => $_POST['e3'],
                    'recycling' => $_POST['e4'],
                    'material'=>$_POST['e5'],
                    'idUser'=>$_POST['idUser'],
                    'idProduct' => $_POST['idProduct']
                    );


        $this->db->insert('Rating', $data);
    }
```

Comment: You should echo output from db in controller. Could you send controller code?

Comment: I updated the post with my controller and model thanks

Comment: Your controller doesn't seem to be loading a view or outputting HTML that would show up in your AJAX response.

Comment: As i can see - there is no returned data at all - simple echo some message to user, if rateProduct returns true/false... Also, you didn't load model in this case, or it is autoloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an indirect answer to your question that "nothing happens", I would suggest a strategy to make sure you that you see at least something happening.

1. in addition to the `success:` handler, also add an `error:` handler with an `alert()` or something.
2. in your success handler, add a `debugger;` statement as the first line. This will cause your browser (chrome, when the development area is visible) to pause execution. This way you can inspect the content of the `data` variable.

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "product/rate",
       data: dataString,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){
            debugger;
            $('#result').html(data);
            },
       error: function() { alert("oops..."); }
       });
```

UPDATE:
In any case, your `rate()` member of the controller should return some valid html, but not directly via `echo` statements but via a view, as described here:
[Codeingiter, manual, static pages](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html)

```
    function rate()
        {
        //...
        $this->load->view('rate/view', $data);
        }
```

given that you have a file **application/views/rate/view.php**:

```
    <?php
    echo 'TODO: put some html code...';
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, Thank you all, it works just fine, didn't know we have to create a special view for that, no **it works like a charm**

Answer (score 1):

Try output some data into rate() function, like:

```
echo "<b>Response to return</b>";
```

Comment: Now I have this kind of message : >Fatal error: ob_start() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in /system/core/Exceptions.php on line 181, **but the echo works**

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the ob_start() error, add `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;` to **config.php**
or set it to false via code:

```
$this->config->set_item('compress_output', FALSE);
```